# Relations between the Eisenstein series and the hypergeometric series

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request, modular-forms, hypergeometric-function

It is known that
$$E_4(\tau) = {}_{2}F_{1}\left(\frac{1}{12}, \frac{5}{12}; 1; \frac{1}{J(\tau)}\right)^4$$
and
$$E_6(\tau) = {}_{2}F_{1}\left(\frac{1}{12}, \frac{7}{12}; 1; \frac{1}{1 - J(\tau)}\right)^6,$$
where $E_{2k}(\tau)$ are the (normalized) Eisenstein series of weight $2k$ and $J(\tau)$ is Klein's invariant. My question is: Are these the only ones? Is there a corresponding identity for $E_2(\tau)$, for example?

Comment: One can easily come up with a formula for $\operatorname{E}_2$ that combines several ${}_2F_1$s, but I have seen none with a single ${}_2F_1$ so far. The usual approach for actual modular forms is to work out a linear differential equation that uses a suitable modular function as independent variable. There are readily applicable formulae for that, but these do not work for $E_2$ which is only quasimodular. That said, I am not aware of a negative result that definitely says it cannot be done.

Comment: As to "the only ones": You can probably give a similar formula for $\operatorname{E}_8$ without difficulty :-)